# pressed in faucet seat evaluation

Tags: plumbing

Is this seat removable? No, vintage.

Will this seat leak?

Will a beveled washer help if it does.

Is there anything a seat dresser can do that i cant do with a grinding stone on a dremel.

[image]

Stem. Sterling 22-1081 is a close fit.

[image]

What is the exact size of this and how do you install it?

[image: NATIONAL BRAND ALTERNATIVE 555251 COLD RENU BARREL BIBB SEAT]

NATIONAL BRAND ALTERNATIVE 555251 COLD RENU BARREL BIBB SEAT

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question or what we're looking at in the pic. Please explain more fully what you're trying to do so we can help you.

Comment: @HoneyDo this is a faucet seat, evaluate it and give feedback regarding the specific areas of concern i listed

Comment: What do the washer holders/stem bottoms look like?

Comment: @ojait amended.

Comment: stems look good. I'm wondering if your faucet need specific washers? Or have they (washers) been pressed into that shape? They look intact and not dried out.

Comment: @ojait Replacement stem bibb retainer is 1mm smaller diameter and takes a 1/4 flat washer.  Ive looked and looked and i cant find any washers similar to the vintage one.

Comment: I've seen this type of washer. I'm relying on memory so bear with me...A "Stepped Washer". I'll put the link at the end of my answer below.

Comment: I was gonna jam this in there because actually the new stem is a half spiral thread too short and almost slips the inside spiral of the cast threads on the faucet body before the bibb washer hits firm. https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B07GVC8PJW/ref=ox_sc_act_image_3?smid=AYI27JSX7SHMW&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Maybe. Yes.
To remove a seat use this tool [image]

You can see at the 10 Oclock position on the seat (2) chips are missing which may cause a opening when the washer is pressed down to stem the water flow.

A beveled washer may make a complete seal rather than a flat washer, but your better off, as you mentioned, to replace or grind the seat. Check/replace both. Replacing is probably the easiest and most assured  way to repair the faucet. Any well stocked hardware store will have an assortment of seats. Take the damaged one with you.

A seat dresser will have a guide for the dressing wheel that keeps it steady and at a 90 degree position for a uniform removal of seat material. [image] Replacing the seat is easier and more likely to be successful at repairing the problem.

[stepped washer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0082797I4)

Comment: The picture is pretty good and i am 99% percent sure i dont see any hex or square fittings for a wrench. Do you agree it must be pressed in?

Comment: It is possible, And if so than you'll need to grind. See edited reply above.